# Wordpress blog post heading disappears in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently working on a Wordpress blog installation. Problem i am facing is when using IE, on main page, when the page is loading, the post heading is visible but after load completes, the blog post heading becomes invisible even though i am able to click in the empty area to open that post. The blog site works fine in other browsers. Theme i am using is "lightword". Any idea what could be the possible problem?

Comment: Please specify which IE version you are using ??

Comment: Check if your template is trying to load a conditional style sheet for IE. If so check it's path is correct. Example's of conditional comments http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source of issue lately. This is caused by "Cufon" found under "Theme Editor" in Wordpress.

"Cufón is a Javascript Dynamic Text Replacement, like sIFR without flash plugin, just javascript." According to an update on Cufon website, UPDATE Oct 24'12: "We have released version 1.09i, which is the same as 1.09 but IE9-compatible"

However, we never used this functionality in our blog, hence Disabled the Cufon instead of updating to a IE9-compatible version and the visibility issue was fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think there is problem of css, in "lighword" theme blog post title are coming in `<canvas> your blog post title </canvas>`, you can see it from firebugs add on of mozilla firefox,

2 solutions

1) you can overwrite it to `<h2> blog post title</h2>` and give css property `.{your div classname} h2 { color: #000000 }`

2) you can directly overwrite  css property `.{your div classname} canvas { color: #000000 }`

hope this will help :)

Comment: Dats d problem, it appears only in IE and i cant use Firebug for my help. Difficult to track down d exact location of the bug

Comment: you can use firebug for IE  "http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ie-webdeveloper-firebug-for-internet-explorer/"

Comment: have you tried after give "!important" property to your h2 or canvas tag, that way, it will override all property of h2 or canvas

Comment: Use fiddler. It will let you to debug it.

Comment: Tried using !important for h2 tag. The thing is while the page is loading, the heading is visible, but once the page load completes, the heading becomes invisible. Tried using z-index for <h2> hoping it might help it get in front but no positive signs. You can have a look at what happens at "www.42gears.com/blog" via IE browser.